# What is the webpack command to build my Laravel and Vue js SPA so that I can deploy it to Live Server?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack

I know that I need to run `npm run build` to build my assets so they are minified for the web. My problem is I'm missing the script in my package.json file and I don't know what the correct code is for this.
package.json:

```
"scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
```

After I run the command it should create the `dist` folder. This is what I need. I'm not sure why my project is missing that script.

Comment: You would execute `npm run production` to create a production ready build. This (out of the box) creates an `app.js` script in the `public` directory that your `master layout` will reference, likely with `script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"` or some variation of there in.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [Laravel Mix section](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#running-mix) of the documentation.

As it states:

> **Mix** is a configuration **layer on top of Webpack**, so to run your Mix
> tasks you only need to execute one of the NPM scripts that is included
> with the default Laravel package.json file:
>
> ```
> // Run all Mix tasks...
> npm run dev
>
> // Run all Mix tasks and minify output...
> npm run production
> ```

This will generate your files in the public directory, by default:

```
/public/js/app.js
/public/css/app.css
```

Of course, you can customize this in the `./webpack.mix.js` to do a bunch of other operations (like copying files, customizing the Webpack config, extracting vendors, etc) that you can see in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix).

Comment: So is this all I need to do to deploy my SPA to a Live server?